# Rendering Blog from rss using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to find the best way to print my posts in my website using Angularjs. I get the post from [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=31e0037a4869eeb55f58c22114816864&_render=json). I have bloque of codes, list, etc.. you can see from [here](http://blog.gonzalobarba.com/how-create-an-api-using-nodejs-express-and-mongodb). So.. I get the Json and I send it propely to the view, you can see the code below:

```
myController.controller('BlogCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=31e0037a4869eeb55f58c22114816864&_render=json')
        .success(function(data){
      $scope.posts = data.value.items;
    }).
        error(function() {
        $scope.error = true;
      });
  }]);
```

First problem I got is when I try to print the {{post.content}} doesn´t render the html, I found this to render the code

```
<div ng-bind-html="expression"></div>
```

but it´s not working for me. Also should be a easy way or a library to print the code directly, I mean the bloque of code like in the website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render HTML, you need to include [`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module:

```
angular.module('myController', ['ngSanitize']);
```

After that you will be able to safely render HTML contents.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/6V8TtmUUhYecQoF66wAj?p=info